# Finding the derivative to nth order

Tags: derivatives

How to find $$\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$$ 
of $$y=\frac{x}{lnx-1}$$

**Appreciated advance**

Answer (score 5):

$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \dfrac{x}{\ln(x)-1} = \dfrac{P_n(\ln(x))}{(\ln(x)-1)^{n+1} x^{n-1}}$$
where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, satisfying
$$ P_{n+1}(t) = ((1-n) t -2) P_n(t)+(t-1) P_n'(t) $$

Answer (score 0):

By applying the quotient rule we have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1 \times (\ln x -1)- \frac{1}{x}x}{(\ln x - 1)^2} = \color{blue}{\frac{\ln x -2}{(\ln x - 1)^2}}$$

Now you can apply the quotient rule again to get $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{x} \times (\ln x -1)^2 - 2(\ln x -1) \frac{1}{x} \times (\ln x - 2)}{(\ln x - 1)^4} =\frac{\frac{1}{x}(\ln x -1)((\ln x-1) -2(\ln x -2))}{(\ln x - 1)^4} = \frac{\frac{1}{x}((\ln x-1) -2(\ln x -2))}{(\ln x - 1)^3}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}(\ln x -2\ln x+3)}{(\ln x - 1)^3}=\frac{(-\ln x+3)}{x(\ln x - 1)^3} = \color{blue}{\frac{-(\ln x-3)}{x(\ln x - 1)^3}}$$

Now do you see a pattern developing it is $$\color{blue}{\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(\ln x -(n+1))}{x^{n-1}(\ln x - 1)^{n+1}}}$$

Comment: Using your formula and Mathematica to comute, say, $y'''$, the results do not agree.

Comment: yep so what's wrong @Jack

Comment: The pattern is in my head .... ghost .... Illusion :D

Comment: yes , at 3rd derivative , pattern is wrong.